# Openstack Keystone as a Service Provider, 401 - Unauthorized Exception for SSO

Tags: openstack, single-sign-on, openid, openstack-keystone

We're currently working on implementing SSO for our university's OpenStack environment using OpenStack Ansible (Yoga version). Our goal is to allow students to log in with their university credentials via an Identity Provider - currently we're using our own Keycloak instance as IdP. The plan is to automatically create a new project for first time users, while returning students will be redirected to their existing projects to manage their instances.

For initial testing, we're directing all users to a single project. Eventually, we would like to script the dynamic creation of projects on the controller node for first-time logins. However, we've run into some problems:

Our Keystone configuration in the user_variables.yml file is as follows:

```
keystone_sp:
  apache_mod: 'mod_auth_openidc'
  cadf_notifications: true
  trusted_dashboard_list:
    - "https://openstack-example.com/auth/websso/"
    - "http://example.keycloak.com/realms/openstack*"
    - "https://openstack-example.com/auth/login/"
  trusted_idp_list:
    - name: "oidc-idp"
      oidc_provider_metadata_url: http://example.keycloak.com/realms/openstack/.well-known/openid-configuration
      oidc_client_id: ********
      oidc_client_secret: *********
      oidc_crypto_passphrase: ******
      oidc_redirect_uri: https://openstack-example.com/v3/OS-FEDERATION/identity_providers/oidc-idp/protocols/openid/auth
      entity_ids:
         - 'http://exmaple.keycloak.com/realms/openstack'
      federated_identities:
        - domain: default
          project: fedproject
          group: fedgroup
          role: member
      protocols:
        - name: openid
          mapping:
            name: openid-mapping
            rules:
              - remote:
                  - type: email
                local:
                  - group:
                      name: fedgroup
                      domain:
                        name: Default
                    user:
                      name: '{0}'
```

This setup is based on the openstack [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ansible-os_keystone/yoga/configure-federation-sp.html#service-provider-configuration-for-oidc-using-mod-auth-openidc). After many attempts with different configurations, this one successfully redirects to our Keycloak IdP for authentication. However, after login, when redirected back to OpenStack, we get a 401 Unauthorised error stating "The request you have made requires authentication".

The SAML tracer logs confirm that Keycloak issues a valid token along with the user information. Despite this, we find no additional error details in the Keystone container, Apache2 and controller logs. This leads me to believe that the problem may lie in the mapping configuration, although it appears to work when tested with the keystone-manage mapping-engine tool. But still, the [doc](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/queens/advanced-topics/federation/mapping_combinations.html#mapping-rules) claims that a 401 exception could be caused by the mapping.

Any insight or suggestions on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated, particularly regarding the mapping process during authentication.

I'm also looking for advice on how to extract more detailed error information. At the moment, the logs don't reveal much beyond the 401 error message. Am I missing something or is this all the information OpenStack typically provides in such cases?

Thank you for your help and guidance.